# String.Format parameters OUT c#

Tags: c#, log4net, out, ref, string.format

I have a system for a store, and they ask me for to put the function of `Log4Net`, the configuration is all ready, my code is

```
String cParameters1 = String.Format("PROJECT:WebERP, CLASS: OrdersMain.aspx.cs, " +
        "METHOD: serviceKardex.GetOrdersDraft \nPARAMETERS:  \nendDate={0} \ninitDate={1}  ", out resGetOrders.ListOrders, ref resGetOrders.Message);
        Log4NetCommon.WriteDebug("DEBUG", cParameters1)
```

well, as you see, just need t convert all the parameters in string for make a record in the log file, but in this example I put the parameters with OUT but isn't work, if a erase that OUT or REF, in the log file they dont appear.

How can I pass or how can I convert that parameters into the `string.format`? The error said "It can't not convert out `resGetOrders.ListOrders` to `object`" Thanks

Comment: Your question isn't at all clear. Why do you *want* to use ref/out? Why are you using a `ListOrders` property for the value of an `endDate` format parameter, and why are you using a `Message` property for an `initDate` format parameter? Those both seem wrong to me.

Comment: Does `PARAMETERS` appear? I wonder if the newline `\n` us stopping them showing.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass `out` and `ref` parameters to `String.Format()`, such a method signature does not exist!

If you just want the words "out" and "ref" to appear in the string logged:

```
string line = String.Format("PROJECT:WebERP, CLASS: OrdersMain.aspx.cs, "
+ "METHOD: serviceKardex.GetOrdersDraft \nPARAMETERS:  \nendDate=out{0} \ninitDate=ref{1}  ", resGetOrders.ListOrders, resGetOrders.Message);
Log4NetCommon.WriteDebug("DEBUG", line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new in this kind of programming, I enter with a group of work, so, I just tried to pass those values with out and ref cos' they used thoso values in others methods, so, the name of the fields like \nendate and inidate doesn't matter, I forgot to change them. If I remove the OUT or REF the function doesn't save.

Whatevere the value that the OUT or the REF brings, there is another way to put them in some variables?
tnks for answer me